# How to dynamically select graphing function in Shiny for R based on input?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to create a page where a graph can be rendered based on the value of a select box in R.  The goal would be to have different kinds of graph rendered (plot, chart, histogram, etc.) according to the selection.

The code I have is this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    computed.visualization <- ExecuteVisualization(
      input$visualization.select
    )

    rendering.function <- SelectRenderingFunction(
      computed.visualization$graphing.function.name
    )

    output$visualization <- rendering.function({
        do.call(
          computed.visualization$graphing.function.name,
          computed.visualization$args
        )
    })
})
```

However, I'm getting an error while getting the value of the input:

```
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. 
(You tried to do something that can only be done from 
inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

What is a good pattern for resolving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In general that error means you needed to make something reactive and you didn't. If you are using a value from the `input` to calculate something else you need to wrap it in a reactive, like so:

```
NewThing<-reactive({ function(input$OldThing) })
```

Then you must refer to the NewThing as `NewThing()` in your code. Without any code I can't say what your exact problem is, but is likely something to do with not using a `reactive` in your `computed.visualization`.

Comment: Thanks!  This seems like it's a very useful construct, but I've found I don't need this complicated structure anymore.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it's not necessary to use different rendering functions for different types of graph, `renderPlot` will do.

```
output$visualization <- renderPlot({
  computed.visualization <- ExecuteVisualization(
    input$visualization.select
  )

  do.call(
    computed.visualization$graphing.function.name,
    computed.visualization$args
  )
})
```

I was working under the incorrect assumption that  different graph objects required different rendering functions.  This way, whatever is returned in `computed.visualization` gets rendered as a plot.

Comment: Also, to achieve something like what I was trying to do (i.e. combine reactive and non-reactive contexts), [this `Shiny` documentation page on `reactiveValues`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html)  looks like the place to go for help.